# MongoDB aggregation - lookup in nested array and merge result to each index

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Please. I need to lookup in nested array and merge result to each index.

I have two collections like this

- Main collection

```
{
    
        "_id": "642d4fb5e49f371387774c4f",
        "createdAt": 1680691125,
        "updatedAt": 1680691125,
        "parent": [
            {
                "detail": null,
                "remark": "sample msg",
                "child": [
                    {
                        "subjectId": "63b563aa3ccaa85ba822967f",
                        "quantity": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "subjectId": "63b563aa3ccaa85ba8229818",
                        "quantity": 5
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    
}
```

- Collection to lookup

```
{
    "_id" : "63b563aa3ccaa85ba822967f",
    "subject_name" : "JAVA",
    "cost" : 1000
},
{
    "_id" : "63b563aa3ccaa85ba8229818",
    "subject_name" : "PHP",
    "cost" : 999
}
```

I need to lookup field 'parent.child.subjectId' and get result into each index of them like this

- Expected Result

```
{
    
        "_id": "642d4fb5e49f371387774c4f",
        "createdAt": 1680691125,
        "updatedAt": 1680691125,
        "parent": [
            {
                "detail": null,
                "remark": "sample msg",
                "child": [
                    {
                        "subjectId": "63b563aa3ccaa85ba822967f",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "subject_name" : "JAVA",
                        "cost" : 1000
                    },
                    {
                        "subjectId": "63b563aa3ccaa85ba8229818",
                        "quantity": 5,
                        "subject_name" : "PHP",
                        "cost" : 999
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    
}
```

I tried with simple lookup but result are outside array

sorry for the inconvenience if i have a mistake conversation. I'm not good in english

thank you very much

Comment: Is it possible to have more than just one `parent`?

Comment: Why does your document has only a single field `data`? It does not look very smart.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sorry, I copied from response from postman. Data may be processed structure before. but in collection have normally structure (without data : {}) I'll edit my post.

Comment: can you please post your query what have you done in your code? @SupawatPothisomphop

Comment: You could try something like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/g8fwsxhjAP_ Then you will have to group you data again if you wanted that way